# Azure Database, EF, Time out issues

Tags: entity-framework, azure, hangfire, azureportal

I have taken over an existing MVC website which uses entity framework and hangfire and is hosted on Azure and uses Azure database. Every so often the website times out.

I'm new to Azure portal, entity framework and hangfire.

If I increase the DTU's it clears the timeout issues?

I'm looking for ways of how to diagnose why the website times out. I have added error logging using elmah and checked hangfire but this doesn't give me any further information.

Is there anything in azure portal that can help?

Answer (score 0):

If it "times out" and if "increasing DTU resolves timeouts" and these observations are true (I think it's on you to really convince yourself this is absolutely true, don't make this assumption lightly) then the usual and obvious candidate is "a slow sql query". Entity Framework is often used with linq to create sql queries without writing sql. These queries are often fine for very simple tasks, such as someData.Where(x=>x.Id == 1).First(), however, if linq is used to join tables, or create complex associations, the generated sql can become monstrously bad, from a performance perspective. You can add logging to write out the sql generated by linq, or you can try to trace the database to see what sql is running on it. If tracing is out of the question, there are still meta queries you can use to view things like cached query plans and SQL Server can give you estimated costs and cached execution counts.

You can still hang yourself without using linq. You can still use stored procedures with EF. Way too many developers are naive about SQL performance *still*; you need to comb over your back end and learn the schema, the stored procedures; inspect the sql contents of everything. Check for any database triggers (easy to miss). Red flags are subqueries, too many joining, too many results from a query, lots of string manipulation in a query, joining tables on strings, or XML/JSON-based SQL work.

Be aware that "slow sql queries" will become slower when load is high. And when slow sql queries build up, they only take more time to resolve. This can also cause debilitating table locking, depending on the nature of the query.

But queries can be performant and still cause locking. ie One table is being written to often and it's blocking other writes or reads from that table. This is a little harder to diagnose, but you can figure it out by carefully inspecting logs of database calls and how long they take to execute. There are also sql queries you can run on the database to diagnose long-running queries, or what tables are locked at a given point in time.

Finally, check for any back end webjobs for your application. If timeouts occur at reoccurring days or times, then somebody's batch SQL could be blocking your production database from being read.

But this is all speculation. I think you need to do more research to determine what is actually causing the site to become unresponsive. If you can log response times for common queries, you can rule out SQL-based latency as being the culprit or not and work from there. There's nothing inherently "amiss" about any of the technologies you specified.

If queries are perfomant but still causing issues, a long term solution is to add something like a message queue and batch your sql work intelligently, or just make the database work asynchronous and not block the UI.

You should correlate any logged timeouts with azure's monitoring. Azure can give you CPU/RAM/page visits and such on the dashboard.

Comment: That's great thanks, I will look into logging response times for common queries. You have given me somewhere to start. I'm at the point of rewriting the project.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure is a bit of a different beast. It doesn't have the on-demand performance of a dedicated DB unless you're prepared to throw serious $$ at it. And even then ...

EF, when written for well can perform quite well. When written poorly it can be a dog, and those problems are compounded on a platform like SQL Azure.

The first thing is to check that your EF contexts are set up to use an execution strategy suited to Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic

The next thing would be to see what kinds of SQL tracing you can run on Azure. Tracing is essential to see what EF is doing behind the scenes. I'm not familiar with tools available for Azure, in my case my Azure experience was running SQL Server on VMs because SQL Azure was too immature, not HIPAA compliant at the time, and expensive for the DTU estimates we were able to get.  Worst case, can you restore an database backup into an SQL Server instance and point a copy of your application environment temporarily at that to run through common usage scenarios? Using an SQL Trace you can pick up on exactly when and how often EF is executing queries, and what queries it is executing.

Things to look at:

- How many queries are running? If you are loading a set of records and expect one query, are there a whole heap of queries getting sent? This would indicate lazy-load calls being triggered.
- What queries are being run? Is it selecting a lot more fields than are being displayed? This would be potentially a case where entire entities are being loaded where a `.Select()` could be used to reduce the amount of data. Perhaps even the case where entire sets of entities are being loaded that aren't relevant to what is displayed/done, such as cases where someone is using `.ToList()` prior to just doing a `.Count()` or `.Any()` or doing a `.FirstOrDefault()` just to do a `!= null` check.
- Is the database properly indexed? Copy some of the heavier queries into SQL Manager and execute them with an execution plan. Are there indexing suggestions?

The common sins of developing with EF and other ORMs boil down to "pulling too much, too often." It's surprising how many clients I've worked with have development teams that have not used a profiler to inspect their ORM use efficiency. (and I'm talking 0% so far.)